# How to create custom connect.sid cookie?

Tags: node.js, express-session, cookie-session

I try to create custom `connect.sid` cookie like `express-session` cookie.
Here example:

```
 const sessionObject = {
        passport:{
            user: id
        }
  }
const cookie = some_function( JSON.stringify(sessionObject), "secret_value" );
```

How can I do this? Or can I use `express-session` for create custom cookie ?
I am interested how to create `sessionId`. I want to test with `jest` my web app.

```
test.only("When signed in , shows logout button", async ()=>{
    const cookieSignature = require('cookie-signature');
    const {Buffer} = require('safe-buffer')
    const keys =require('../config/keys')

    const id = "64738814bf2b6f3045d16c0a"

    const sessionObject = {
        passport:{
            user: id
        }
    }
    const session = Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(sessionObject)).toString('base64');
    
    
    const signature = cookieSignature.sign(sessionString, keys.cookieKey );
    
    await page.setCookie({name: "connect.sid", value:signature})

    
    await page.goto("http://localhost:3000")
    
})
```

It dont work. Because here has `sessionId` creating problem. When I add original value testing work like this:

```
await page.setCookie({name: "connect.sid", value:"s%3AjPRlxI6YhH-sW0sw7wPYt8DpbVJa7B3B.efgIks6qmsm29kmEpazCYjO74JEToEizrlWwGe1RjuA"})
```

How to create `session_id`? If someone have any idea please write comment or answer